# Established html table line to python

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

Let's say, i have an HTML Table like this:

```
<tr>
  <td class="Klasse gerade">12A<br></td>
  <td class="Stunde gerade">4<br></td>
  <td class="Fach gerade">GEO statt GE<br></td>
  <td class="Lehrer gerade"><br></td>
  <td class="Vertretung gerade">Herr Grieger<br></td>
  <td class="Raum gerade">603<br></td>
  <td class="Anmerkung gerade"><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="Klasse gerade">10A<br></td>
  <td class="Stunde gerade">2<br></td>
  <td class="Fach gerade">MA statt GE<br></td>
  <td class="Lehrer gerade"><br></td>
  <td class="Vertretung gerade">Herr Grieger<br></td>
  <td class="Raum gerade">406<br></td>
  <td class="Anmerkung gerade"><br></td>
</tr>
```

if phrase the HTML to python(2.7) with:

```
link = "http://www.test.com/vplan.html"
f = urllib.urlopen(link)
vplan = f.read()
print vplan
```

how can i do this?: **if** td=10A **then** print the complete tr of 10A

Sorry for the bad formulation but this is in my opinion the easiest was to explain my question and don't wonder about the German word's (I'm a German)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an HTML parser like *Beautifulsoup*.  Assuming the table in question is the only one or the first one in the document, the program may look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main():
    link = 'http://www.test.com/vplan.html'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(link), 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table')
    rows = [x.find_parent('tr') for x in table.find_all(text='10A')]
    for row in rows:
        for cell in row.find_all('td'):
            print cell.text
        print '-' * 10
```